# How to send user information through Dynamic Links via Firebase Invites

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I am trying to implement Firebase Invites feature in my app. Main logic is that the user select his/her friends in the contacts list and they will send invitation via Firebase Invites to achive this i want to send some peace of information about the user to recognise by my app. On the other end his/her friend will receive a Dynamic Link(I think that's how Firebase Invites work) via Email/SMS and if he/she opens it then according to the data in that Dynamic Link the user is going ask to add him as his/her friend. 
According to Firebase Docs i can see this code

```
if let invite = FIRInvites.inviteDialog() {
    invite.setInviteDelegate(self)

// NOTE: You must have the App Store ID set in your developer console project   
    // in order for invitations to successfully be sent.

    // A message hint for the dialog. Note this manifests differently   depending on the
    // received invation type. For example, in an email invite this appears as the subject.

    invite.setMessage("Try this out!\n -(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.name)")

// Title for the dialog, this is what the user sees before 
sending the invites.
        invite.setTitle("Invites Example")
        invite.setDeepLink("app_url")
        invite.setCallToActionText("Install!")
        invite.setCustomImage("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
        invite.open()
      }
```

My question here is how can i create a "app_url" with user information to send in `invite.setDeepLink("app_url")` method. And how to handle it in the friend side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dynamic Link in the Firebase console:

1. Open the Firebase console.
2. Open the Dynamic Links page by clicking Dynamic Links on the sidebar menu. On this page, you can see a list of your Dynamic Links and their click rates.
3. Click New Dynamic Link and ensure that Generate Dynamic Link is selected.
4. Provide basic information for the Dynamic Link. [see documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios)

Not sure about handling it in the "friend side."

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply can you please tell me how to create a dynamic link programatically by adding something like Name to it.